# Tensorboard is not showing the output in tansorboard_in_notebook. ipynb example

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I am trying to learn tensorboard in colab in this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb)

when I am trying to launch tensorboard, it runs without any problems but the output is not displayed as shown in this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnRyO.gif)

Could you help me to know how to overcome this issue?

thank you

**Note:**
I am using OS: Windows 10
browser: Chrome version 95

Comment: It works on Edge browser, but why is not working on Chrome?

Comment: It takes some time to load. 10-20 sec, maybe.

Comment: I waited much longer, but nothing happened

Comment: I tried it in Google Colab (Chrome 95), it took 15 sec to load. And, it is working fine. Try restarting the notebook, and please don't scroll or click anywhere, let it load.